When should I call for service with water in the water heater drip pan?
There is some, very little, water in the water heater drip pan. The drain valve is dry. The Professional Classic Rheem unit is 6.5 years old and is located in a closet. The indoor AC unit is above the water tank and the filter is dry.
The AC is serviced twice a year. We turn the water heater off when not using hot water, so it is mostly off. It only takes 20 min to heat water hot enough for one shower. We are in Florida.
Should I call the AC guys who installed the AC system and the water heater, or wait? I am on the second floor in a 2 story building.


@crip659 It is PROE38 S2 RH95 B Model, 45 gallons; 6 years warranty. The prior owner' unit lasted almost 20 years. I have yet to figure out what you are talking about. I mean the pressure relieve valve.

The hose attached to the white elbow going into the drain pan should go right to the pressure relief valve.  That valve is made to open if the temperature and/or pressure gets too high in the tank.  They also tend to develop a slow leak if dirt/sediment stops them from closing completely.

@crip659 all we can tell there is that there's a low spot in the pan where the water is.

@crip659 I have yet to find the pressure relief valve. Searching for the installation instructions

"We turn the water heater off when not using hot water, so it is mostly off." That probably killed your hot water heater. You're exposing it to thermal cycling and stress that doesn't happen to anybody else.

@user71659 Makes sense, thank you. Yet, I asked the a/c technician if it is okay to turn the water heater off when not using hot water. He said yes. Besides, the water is never really cold in Florida, in fact it gets hot without heating since it is always hot outside.

@MacBook By default, the water in the tank is 120 F, though many people set it to 140 F. for Legionnaire's Disease. That's also a major safety issue, by turning off the heater, the water spends time in the danger zone for Legionnaire's, so saving a few bucks on power can lead to severe illness. The point seems to be that an HVAC technician is not a plumber.

@user71659 Thank you. Nobody ever said this to me. Neither upon installation of the new water heater, nor during preventative maintenance service.

You've done most of what I'd do before considering replacement of the unit. If both exterior valves are fully closed and dry inside, and if nothing above the unit could be the cause, it must be leaking internally. That usually means a rusted-through tank.
You can also check whether the area immediately inside any service panels is wet without an obvious leak point in something like piping. That's fairly solid confirmation that something has failed that isn't serviceable.
